# Regex to delete consecutive lines with a specific symbol

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a huge text file to sort and I noticed that the lines I don't need usually come with a hyphen `-` symbol and more than 3 lines in a row. So I want to use regex to remove these lines.

I tried this: `^.*(?:\-.*?){3}.*(?:\R|\Z)` but it works only within a single line while I need to remove only consecutive lines with `-` starting from 3 and more.

Example of my text:

```
Good Line 1
Error-1
Error-2:3045
Error-3-32
Good Line 2
Error-4_sub
Error-5.0
Error-6...0
Error-7
Error-8-9
Error-9
Good Line 3
```

desired output

```
Good Line 1
Good Line 2
Good Line 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^.*?-.*(?:\R|\z)){4,}`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                 # Beginning non capture group
^                   # beginning of line
  .*?               # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  -                 # hyphen
  .*                # 0 or more any character but newline
  (?:\R|\z)         # non capture group, any kind of linebreak OR end of file
){4,}               # end group, must appear 4 or more times
                        # set the value to your needs
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

---

**Bookmark lines:**

[image]

Comment: where to set the number of lines to delete? it remove all lines with -. but I need to remove consecutive lines starting from 3 and more

Comment: @darjuha: Sorry, I've miised that constraint, see my edit. Here I remove 4 or more lines. Just use the value you want instead of 4.

Comment: when I bookmark lines with your regex just to see what it delete. I noticed that it bookmark only the first word of the group, any chance to bookmark all group?

Comment: @darjuha:Works for me, see the last screenshot.

Comment: set everything like on your screen and still not work, but why I don't understand - https://i.imgur.com/P7H9wFg.jpg

Comment: @darjuha: May be a version problem, here I have `v7.8.5 64-bit`, Windows 10

Comment: seem's like that, tried in newest version and it worked as I wanted. and one more thing, I tried different symbols instead of - and it worked good, but for dot it not working. so do I need some other regex for dot or add something to this one? cause it work weird currently with dot (if we replace - with dot and run that regex)

Comment: @darjuha: Dot is a special character within a regex, you have to escape it: `\.`

Comment: @darjuha: If it works for you, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: yea, sure. all works perfectly now. thanks so much Toto. and sorry for my annoying questions, I'm a total noob in all this he he

Answer (score 0):

I would use ...
Find what: `^(?:.*Error-).*\s?`
Replace with: `nothing` 
This will find any line that have `Error-` and remove it....

**Explanation**

```
  ^                   # beginning of line
  (?:                 # Beginning non capture group  
  .*               # 0 or more any character but newline,   
  Error-           # literally  Error plus hyphen   
  )                    # closing of non captured group   
  .*                # 0 or more any character but newline  
  \s              # matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ])  
   ?               # matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Comment: An suggestion that works for 99% of the lines in a huge file is a really bad idea because there is no way of knowing what has happened to the other 1% of the lines. Have they been wrongly modified? Have then been wrongly left alone? How would one know?

Comment: I have no idea what your comment means. If it actually means something useful then you should [edit] the answer to clearly explain both the 99% and the 1%. Please compare this answer against those written by people like Wictor and Toto. Notice how much care and attention they put into explaining how their answers work and how they achieve what the question wanted.

Comment: I edited my answer,  and removed my comments,